# Is there a solution for xlsxwriter error in python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I am working on analyzing data on python and export it to Excel so I used `xlwt` library in one file and another file used `xlsxwriter`. However, when using function `workbook.write()` with `xlsxwriter`, to assign the values to Excel, I got this weird error. Even though I scanned the Internet and Googled this error, and wrote the code correctly, I still couldn't find solution to this error. Furthermore, I would like to plot the curves in Excel (scatter plot) and I wasn't able to plot the curves.

Does anyone can help me fix this error and how to plot graph in excel from python? I also installed the `openpyxl` library.

I am using Pycharm as an editor for Python 3.7
this is my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy import ndimage
import math
import random as rand
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
# import openpyxl module
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('image_analysis.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
image = cv2.imread('D:\My work\MASTERS WORK\Sample H 4  1 2020\Sample H1\SampleH1_#2_72pxfor1cm_out.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+ cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh=thresh/255
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
h,w =image.shape[:2]
print('The dimensions of the image =',h,w)
# Compute Euclidean distance from every binary pixel
# to the nearest zero pixel then find peaks
distance_map = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(thresh)
local_max = peak_local_max(distance_map, indices=False, min_distance=20, labels=thresh)
# Perform connected component analysis then apply Watershed
markers = ndimage.label(local_max, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]
labels = watershed(-distance_map, markers, mask=thresh)
# Iterate through unique labels
n = 0
Areas = []
row = 2
col = 0
gamma = 2.6
W =[]
style = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
workbook.write(0,col, "AREA",style)
workbook.write(0,col+1, "Raduis",style)
workbook.write(0,col+2, "Volume",style)
workbook.write(0,col+3,  "Weight",style)
workbook.write(0,col+4 ,  "Raduis(cm)",style)
workbook.write(0,col+5 ,  "Weight(gm)",style)
workbook.write(0,col+6 ,  "Sorted raduis",style)
workbook.write(0,col+7 ,  "Sorted weight",style)
workbook.write(0,col+8,  "Cumulative weight",style)
workbook.write(0,col+9,  "% passing",style)
workbook.write(0,col+10,  "Diameter (mm)",style)
raduis=[]
for item in Areas:
    r = ((item/math.pi)**0.5) # raduis is in cm units
    raduis.append(r)
    v = (4/3)*math.pi*r**3  # volume in cubic cm units and considered as sphere
    w = gamma*v # weight is in gram units
    workbook.write(row, col, item)
    workbook.write(row, col + 1, r)
    workbook.write(row, col + 2, v)
    workbook.write(row, col + 3, w)
    row += 1

    r=2
    s=[]
    for k in raduis:
        r2 = k/scale
        s.append(r2)
        workbook.write(r, col + 4, r2)
        weight = (4/3)*3.141592*2.6*r2**3
        workbook.write(r, col + 5, weight)
        W.append(weight)
        r+=1
```

But I got this error:

> File "D:/My work/My images/Watershed_seg.py", line 94, in 
>       workbook.write(0,col, "AREA",style)
>   AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `worksheet.write` ?

Comment: Unfortunately , it is very weird error .. it works well only using xlwt library

Comment: All those `workbook.write()` calls should be `worksheet.write()`.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much .. it worked very well